# Creating a function for displaying status updates with printf style string formatting on an MFC control

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, dialog, atl

I needed to display status updates on a dialog box, and wanted to be able to send `printf` style formatted strings to it. In addition I would like that function to call a similar function which will add the formatted data to a log file.

Assuming my Static control is called `IDC_MYSTATUSBAR`, the function looks like this:

```
void MyDialog::ShowStatus(LPCWSTR lpText, ...)
{
    CString sMsg;
    va_list ptr;
    va_start(ptr, lpText);
    if (*ptr == 0)
       sMsg = lpText;
    else
       sMsg.FormatV(lpText, ptr);
    va_end(ptr);
    CWinApp *myApp = AfxGetApp();
    if (myApp)
    {
        CWnd *pWnd = myApp->m_pMainWnd;
        if (pWnd)
        {
            ::SetDlgItemText(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_MYSTATUSBAR, sMsg.GetString());
        }
    }
    myLogFunction(L"%s", sMsg.GetString());
}
```

The function is called as follow:

```
ShowStatus(L"The results are %d.", 100);
```

or

```
ShowStatus(L"Server returned the following result: %s", L"result");
```

However other modules and libraries calls my function by having a member variable called `logfunc` which is defined as:

```
typedef void(*logFunc)(LPCWSTR lpText, ...);
```

and in that case, the code from the other module will look like:

```
logFunc m_logfunc;      
if (m_logfunc) m_logfunc(L"Internet Time: (%d) %s Local Time = %s", result, TimeResult.FormatGmt(L"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"), CurrentTime.FormatGmt(L"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"));
```

In most cases it works perfectly and the output looks like this:
[image]

However, sometimes the `%` switches are shown instead of the data and then it looks like:
[image]

I tried to understand further why it fails, so the function call that fails is:

```
int ct = GetCurrentTransactionNo();
if (m_logfunc)
    m_logfunc(L"Checking transaction no. %d.", ct);
```

But if I change it to:

```
int ct = 15;
if (m_logfunc)
    m_logfunc(L"Checking transaction no. %d.", ct);
```

I get a correct formattted string.
[image]

Comment: With this snippet, I tested and cannot reproduce your problem. Could you please show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information? And try to catch any possible exceptions.

Comment: I would try two things: made `ct` as const, and I would replace `%d` with `%i`. See what happen next.

Comment: @flaviu2 - that didn't change anything. Now it shows "Checking transaction no. %i"

Comment: @AndrewTruckle do you mean calling ::Format in my function, or replacing my function with 2 calls:
1. Format
2. Display the status message
So the answer is to be able to call a single function for any status update.

Comment: `typedef void(*logFunc)(LPCWSTR lpText, ...)` - That's missing a calling convention. That's pretty significant when crossing module boundaries (or even just compilation units). At any rate, with the information provided, the issue cannot be reproduced. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle any idea what can cause the problem?

Comment: Undefined behavior is pretty much the only reason. If you need a solid answer, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable - I updated the question with a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: Another meaningful test would be to check what happens if you pass 3 arguments to the function, and the 2nd one is zero or NULL. Or if you call it with an explicit (int) cast. Implicit type conversions can often cause troubles. And what does the m_logfunc function do? It is declared with variable args too. Does it call MyDialog::ShowStatus()? How does it form the args list then, etc, etc. Looks like a zero value acts as a terminator.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou it forms the args using ‘va_list()’ The source code of ShowStatus() is part of the question.

Comment: `m_logfunc` is a different function though. Is it somehow mapped to ShowStatus() or calls it? Or you mean the code in the implementation of `m_logfunc` was copied to ShowStatus()? I mean it's not very clear how the two functions relate.

Comment: Note I deleted my comments because I overlooked that in your code you were already using `CString::Format` so it is best to remove your obsolete responses.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou it is mapped as explained in the question.

Comment: If you run your app in debug mode you could step into the offending example to see what `FormatV` does and ascertain why it fails maybe.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - I have done that and in the problematic cases I can see that after calling FormatV sMsg contains some "%" characters. In other words FormatV fails, but I don't know why...

Comment: See my answer which also addresses your comment.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please provide a [mcve] (needs to be minimal **and** complete).

Comment: Having asked for a [mcve] 4 times without getting one, I'm voting to close this off. Your code is broken, but you decided to keep the broken code private. This isn't going to make for a useful Q&A.

Comment: @IInspectable - I updated the question with a minimal reproducible example but I need to find further failure cases.

Comment: That's *"minimal"*, but not *"reproducible"*. The issue is - most likely - related to the way you assign the function pointer to a function object (there's a destructive cast in there, one way or another). If you are genuinely looking for a solution, create a [mcve]. The easiest way to go about this is to create a console application. Use Visual Studio's *"Windows Desktop Wizard"*, select *"Console Application (.exe)"*, and tick the *"MFC headers"* option.

Comment: @IInspectable - my latest update (Update #3) runs with no problems,  so right now, I am unable to reproduce the problem but am working on it...

Comment: I am trying to create a minimal reproducable example in this public repo: https://github.com/haephrati/TestCode

Comment: Please remember to update the question when you reproduce the problem.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo - I sure will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the first parameter passed to the function is 0 or "", `*ptr` (which is in fact `*ptr[0]` or `*(ptr + 0)`, hence the first block in memory) will hold null, thus the function printed the string literally, without formatting it with `FormatV()`.

You need to replace the following block

```
if (*ptr == 0)
    sMsg = lpText;
else
    sMsg.FormatV(lpText, ptr);
```

with just

```
sMsg.FormatV(lpText, ptr);
```

Comment: You tried to fix code that didn't need fixing. In doing so you made things worse by choosing ANSI encoding and placing an arbitrary limit of 99 code units on the formatted string. This isn't useful.

Comment: Also, is it worth explaining the difference between comparing *ptr and ptr again null? So that he understands why it was wrong? But well done for fixing it. 

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, when the first parameter passed to the function is 0 or "", *ptr be equal to 0, as the first block in memory will hold null.

Answer (score 3):

I think as others have implied is that the issue is with undefined behaviour.

You have already ascertained that the issue with with values of `0` that cause the problem. Well, `0` can also be considered as a `nullptr` (or **null pointer**).

I am not in a position to verify my explanation but think that your parameter list of `0` might be construed as a null pointer (no arguments) and thus the return value is the format string unchanged.

Maybe you should consider having a bespoke resolution for when the value you are passing is `0` and handle it in a different way. For example (I am not sure if you can use an overloaded function with same name):

```
void MyDialog::ShowStatus2(LPCWSTR lpText, int iValue)
{
    CString sMsg;
    sMsg.Format(lpText, iValue);
    CWinApp *myApp = AfxGetApp();
    if (myApp)
    {
        CWnd *pWnd = myApp->m_pMainWnd;
        if (pWnd)
        {
            ::SetDlgItemText(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_MYSTATUSBAR, sMsg.GetString());
        }
    }
    myLogFunction(L"%s", sMsg.GetString());
}
```

---

> I have done that and in the problematic cases I can see that after calling `FormatV sMsg` contains some "%" characters. In other words `FormatV` fails, but I don't know why.

When you are in debug mode you might find it useful to look at what the value of `ptr` is as that contains the parsed arguments. When the passed in value for this argument is `0` to need to see if `ptr` is null or not.

Comment: The problem is that I am not only passing integers, or one integer but all kinds of combinations of any types so I don't see a point creating a separate ShowStatus2() just to handle an int parameter. The entire idea is to support any types and any number of parameters.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati The point my friend is that a single `int` with a value `0` can be considered `null`. So it is a special case you must account for.

Comment: Got it, but what about several arguments that the first of them is 0? also in some cases %s is not handled properly.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati I don’t know enough about the logic of the variable arguments mechanics to comment on that aspect.

Comment: That's not how `va_list` works. Internally, it's just a pointer. There is no information on the number of available arguments, nor is there any special logic that tries to determine the end of the list. The driver is the format string, which advances the pointer whenever a placeholder is encountered. It doesn't care whether the new pointer is valid. It just uses it, cheerfully supporting you in exploring the vast space that is undefined behavior. C++ solves this with parameter packs, introduced in C++11, a decade ago.

Comment: See: https://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2016/01/27/introduction-to-c++-variadic-templates/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with parameter packs, introduced in C++11

```
class Temp
{

public:
  template< typename ... Type >
  static void ShowStatus( LPCWSTR lpText, Type ... args )
  {
    CString sMsg;
    sMsg.Format( lpText, args... );
    MessageBox( NULL, sMsg.GetString(), L"", MB_OK );
  }
};


int main()
{
  int ct = 0;
  wchar_t test[] = L"this is a test";
  Temp::ShowStatus( L"%d", ct );
  Temp::ShowStatus( L"%s", test );
  Temp::ShowStatus( L"%d %s", ct, test );
}
```